# Export-Excel Powershell Module cannot tranfer all columns - formatting

Tags: regex, powershell, module, sqlcmd

I am doing MySql DB queries pipeline and using results to transfer data do Storage Account.
For DB query and tranfer data to file .txt I use this command:

```
sqlcmd -S $(Server_prod) -i "G:\DB_Automation\xxx\Night_Batch_Report_4.sql" -o "G:\DB_Automation\SQL_Queries\xxx\4th_init.txt"
```

Later I use that cript to tranfer all that was inside .txt file to .xlsx format.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
                  displayName: Tranfer 4st night job --> Excel
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      $rawData = Get-Content -Path 'G:\DB_Automation\SQL_Queries\Results\Night_batch\1st_init.txt' | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}
                      $delimiter = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator 
                      ($rawData -replace '\s+' , $delimiter) | Set-Content -Path 'G:\DB_Automation\SQL_Queries\Results\Night_batch\theNewFile.csv'
                      Import-Csv -Path 'G:\DB_Automation\SQL_Queries\Results\Night_batch\theNewFile.csv' | Export-Excel -Path 'G:\DB_Automation\SQL_Queries\Results\Night_batch\batch_audit_report_$(Build.BuildNumber)_prod_Night.xlsx' -Autosize -WorkSheetname '04-Check all task completed'
```

The issue with this approach is that I can see many more content to be tranferd in .txt file than later lands in .xlsx.
Please refer to to screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Some columens are not tranfered.

Can you pls tell me if it's there an issue with PowerShell script / formatting?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

I have modified it to be now:

```
              $text = Get-Content -Raw -Path 'G:\DB_Automation\xxx\Night_batch\8th_init.txt' 
              $rawData = ($text -split "\(\d* rows affected\)")[1].Trim() -split "\n"
              $delimiter = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator 
              $data = ($rawData -replace '\s+' , $delimiter) | ConvertFrom-Csv
              $data | Export-Excel -Path 'G:\DB_Automation\xxx\Night_batch\batch_audit_report_$(Build.BuildNumber)_prod_Night.xlsx' -Autosize -WorkSheetname '08-t_team_role_conn'
```

But now....
For some queries it works fine (image below):
[image]
but for some I get empty Excel sheet, dispite queries are done well.
[image]

[image]

Can you shed some light on this issue?

---

**Releated Issue**

All works fine, except this: if you take a look on the cell you will find date separated from time.
In that case script would not pick whole cell but will divide content to date and time and will push it as new columns.
Is thare a way to get only particular content of a cell instead of deviding it?[image]

Comment: As an aside: If you use `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator` as the separator to generate your CSV data, you must use `-UseCulture` with `Import-Csv`, because `Import-Csv` (and also `Export-Csv`) by default uses `,` regardless of what the current culture is.

Comment: Even though you mention MySQL, the use of `sqlcmd` suggests MSSQL (Microsoft SQL Server). With the latter, you can avoid the need for text parsing if you use `Invoke-SqlCmd ... | Export-Excel ...` instead - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976218/45375).

Comment: Also note that your screenshot shows that your query returned no rows at all.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

The problem is your attempt to extract a *.csv file from the raw data in your first screenshot isn't working properly.

If you start with this:

```
$lines = @"
Changed database context to 'GPF_PROD_DB'

(0 rows affected)
entry_time batch_run_num batch_name batch_id task_name task_id primary_key chunk_id
---------- ------------- ---------- -------- --------- ------- ----------- --------
       aaa           bbb        ccc      ddd       eee     fff         ggg      hhh

(1 rows affected)
"@ -split "`n"
```

and your code:

```
$rawData = $lines | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}
$delimiter = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator 
($rawData -replace '\s+' , $delimiter)
```

you get:

```
Changed,database,context,to,'GPF_PROD_DB'
(0,rows,affected)
entry_time,batch_run_num,batch_name,batch_id,task_name,task_id,primary_key,chunk_id
----------,-------------,----------,--------,---------,-------,-----------,--------
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh
(1,rows,affected)
```

and when you read that back in with `Import-Csv` it takes column headers from the first row - there's only 5 columns so it discards the data in any additional columns (i.e `task_id` onwards).

Exporting this data to excel (or even back to a CSV with `Export-Csv` will only write the data from the first 5 columns since that's all that is being imported.

#### Workaround

You need to extract *just* the tabular data rows from your source text file.

I don't know how fragile this approach would be, but you could split on the `(x rows affected)` and take the second result from the text file - e.g.:

```
# use "Get-Content -Raw" to read the file as a single string in your code
$text = @"
Changed database context to 'GPF_PROD_DB'

(0 rows affected)
entry_time batch_run_num batch_name batch_id task_name task_id primary_key chunk_id
---------- ------------- ---------- -------- --------- ------- ----------- --------
       aaa           bbb        ccc      ddd       eee     fff         ggg      hhh

(1 rows affected)
"@

$rawData = ($text -split "\(\d* rows affected\)")[1].Trim() -split "\n" `
    | foreach-object -begin { $i = 0 } -process { if( $i -ne 1 ) { $_ } $i++ } `
    | foreach-object { $_.Trim() }
```

What this does is:

- `($text -split "\(\d* rows affected\)")` - split the entire text file into chunks based on separators in the format "(x rows affected)"
- `[1]` - take the second chunk - i.e. the one that contains the tabular data (the array is zero-indexed, so 1 is the second item in the array)
- `.Trim()` - remove leading and trailing whitespace including line breaks
- `-split "\n"` - split the chunk into lines
- `foreach-object -begin { $i = 0 } -process { if( $i -ne 1 ) { $_ } $i++ }` - filters the lines of text in the selected chunk and removes the second one (that contains the `-------` column header underlines)
- `foreach-object { $_.Trim() }` - finally trims the remaining lines of text

The result is equivalent to :

```
$rawData = @(
    "entry_time batch_run_num batch_name batch_id task_name task_id primary_key chunk_id",
    "aaa           bbb        ccc      ddd       eee     fff         ggg      hhh"
)
```

and now you can process it like you already were:

```
$delimiter = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator

# no need to write to a file and re-import - just use ConvertFrom-Csv
$data = ($rawData -replace '\s+', $delimiter) | ConvertFrom-Csv

$data | Export-Excel -Path ...
```

The result should look like this in Excel:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | entry_time | batch_run_num | batch_name | batch_id | task_name | task_id | primary_key | chunk_id |
| 2 | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd | eee | fff | ggg | hhh |

This might break if your source file format changes, but it'll hopefully point you in the right direction...

---

#### Notes

- Updated to discard the line of `------` header underlines in the output from sqlcmd - thanks @mklement0!

Comment: +1 for the explanation and the fundamentals of the approach, but note that `sqlcmd`'s output also has a separator line below the header line.
The question mentions MySQL, but the use of `sqlcmd` suggests MSSQL. With the latter, you can avoid the need for text parsing if you use `Invoke-SqlCmd ... | Export-Excel ...` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976218/45375).
Otherwise, `sqlcmd.exe` output could be optimized for easier parsing / direct CSV output (with limitations); see the other answers to the linked post, notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7259937/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 - I've updated to exclude the row of underscores - thanks for the tip :-). Like you say, there are probably better ways to access the data if the OP can alter the upstream process to use ```Invoke-SqlCmd``` instead, but this answer will hopefully help if they're limited to only processing the log file...

Comment: @mklement0 - I do usually use ```###``` headings, but subconsciously decided to reduce the wear on my ```#``` key today so only typed ```##```. I just made the headings smaller by putting another one in with ```ctrl-c \ ctrl-v``` though :-).

Comment:  ...............

Comment: @MichałPicheta - feel free to accept the answer if it helped (click the grey tick to the left of the answer). It’s probably worth posting your update as a follow-up question…

Comment: @MichałPicheta: an empty output spreadsheet implies that your query returned _no results_ (no rows) and `$data` was therefore `$null` (which is what happens when `Import-Csv` reads a CSV file that contains headers only).

Comment: I got you..works very well except it divides content of cell and splits it as a new cells.

Comment: @MichałPicheta: That suggests that the values returned by the query themselves contain whitespace. If you stick with the `sqlcmd` approach, you must therefore choose a different separator with the `-s` option, namely one that you know not to occur inside values. Given that this answers addresses your problem as originally presented, I suggest accepting it, and if you get stuck addressing the new requirements, please ask a new question, as suggested.

Comment: @MichałPicheta - another option is to look for different logic to parse the tabular data - from memory I think mklement0 has answered a question in the distant past about how to do this by taking the underscores as column width markers and breaking lines on those boundaries...

Comment: @mclayton, in fact, we _both_ did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66784512/45375

Comment: So in my case I got rid of first line "Changed database context to 'GPF_PROD_DB'." by using expression: $text = Get-Content -Raw -Path'G:\DB_Automation\SQL_Queries\Results\Night_batch\3rd_init.txt' 
$text[1..$text.count] | set-content G:\DB_Automation\SQL_Queries\Results\Night_batch\3rd_init.txt but I do not understand this part from your method: [pscustomobject] $oht # Convert to [pscustomobject] and output. How can this object $oht can be used here? Can I use it with ohers expressions like:                       $delimiter = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator .. ?

Comment: @MichałPicheta: the code in the linked answers outputs _objects_ rather than strings, which you can directly pipe to `Export-Excel`.