How to parse fixed position data into hashtable in powershell
Unfortunately none of the referred answers are remotely solving the issue.
Most of the solutions are either generic and do not apply or too specific to their related issues.
I have the output of 7-zip app, when I calculate hashcode of a given folder: ."$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe" h C:\temp\ | select -skiplast 10 -skip 6
CRC32             Size  Name
-------- -------------  ------------
                        Temp\
54D2639E          1274  Temp\.log
                        Temp\CC\
362CADDA         15360  Temp\CC\install.log
7D41A917         19204  Temp\exitCode7.zip
63EB42A5       1003850  Temp\master.hash.txt

I want to parse that into powershell array of hashtables
$(
  ${CRC32='value', Size='value', Name='value' },
   ...
)


do you have control over the code exporting this data?

Welcome to SO, Deian. Please read the information at https://stackoverflow.com/help to learn how SO works. Please make special note of the need for the question to contain an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example) as well as a description of what does happen and what should happen. Without the code you are trying to make work, the question may attract downvotes and votes to close.

Have a look at the answers to this question - there’s 2 different answers that show ways to parse fixed-width tabular text (disclaimer - one is mine :-)) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66779538/powershell-parse-datetime-string-to-datetime-object

If you looking for an of-the-shelf solution, you might try this ConvertFrom-SourceTable cmdlet. For examples, see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ConvertFrom-SourceTable%22

Deain: @iRon's impressive ConvertFrom-SourceTable script (which you can install with, e.g.,  Install-Script ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Scope CurrentUser or, in PowerShell 7, with Install-PSResource ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Scope CurrentUser) can handle your data format by default (no parameters needed) and it is a good command to have installed in general, as it is quite versatile. If you still want to roll your own solution: this answer to the first duplicate now works with your data format too.

it feel like you steering the solution towards specific solution .. I dont believe this is the spirit of SO...
Why would I use some library like ConvertFrom-SourceTable when the solution of a problem like thatis like 20 lines function, which we can share here ...
Please unlock my question I am ready to post my solution

@Deian: Your question is a duplicate, and the first linked duplicate has an answer that works as-is with your data (except if you want to output (ordered) hashtables, replace [pscustomobject] $oht with just $oht). Given that your question is a duplicate, "steering" you towards an off-the-shell solution was merely a courtesy, in response to you later updating the closed question. What isn't in the spirit of SO is to ask questions that are conceptually clearly duplicates and differ only in details. If you have a solution to share, I suggest doing it there.
